# Removal of sharing secret key to users

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

Is there a way to avoid secret key sharing when using ssh key access to multiple users for accessing EC2 Instances. Can this be achieved by any of the method. Is IAM resources helpful for this?

the following is the terraform code i have so far implemented:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = ""
  secret_key = ""
  region     = "eu-north-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "new" {
  # ...instance configuration...
  ami                         = "ami-4bd45f35"
    availability_zone           = "eu-north-1b"
    ebs_optimized               = true
    instance_type               = "t3.medium"
    monitoring                  = false
    key_name                    = "new"
    subnet_id                   = "subnet-5af3f122"
    vpc_security_group_ids      = ["sg-0a4f03bc2ee1fda8b"]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    private_ip                  = "172.16.1.101"
    source_dest_check           = true

    root_block_device {
        volume_type           = "gp2"
        volume_size           = 8
        delete_on_termination = true
    }
}
resource "aws_iam_user" "lb" {
  name = "loadbalancer"
  path = "/system/"

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tag-value"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "lb" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "lb_ro" {
  name = "test"
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show a [mcve] of your Terraform code and how you access it and how you'd like to extend things? Do you use an off the shelf AMI or make your own?

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code as is?

Comment: I have an EC2 instance (Ubuntu) that I have created using the AWS console and added a new user using ssh command. using the secret key the user can access the account. then I have a situation, where I cannot share my secret keys with users then I have heard about IAM resources. which can help in achieving what I want using terraform. so, I have imported it into terraform. now i am trying to add users to my EC2 instance in terraform using the following information from this link. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html .

Comment: but, I didn't find any tutorials or blogs in creating user access without sharing secret key or using terraform in clear steps. so I would like to have help in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) to simplify access to your instances.

Quoted from the doc :

> With EC2 Instance Connect, you can control SSH access to your
>   instances using AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies as
>   well as audit connection requests with AWS CloudTrail events. In
>   addition, you can leverage your existing SSH keys or further enhance
>   your security posture by generating one-time use SSH keys each time an
>   authorized user connects. Instance Connect works with any SSH client,
>   or you can easily connect to your instances from a new browser-based
>   SSH experience in the EC2 console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i have created an EC2 instance connect using Amazon console. now i want to know how can i manage and control the ssh key access mainly by not sharing my secret key to users. could you simplify my problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: When Instance Connect is properly configure, there is no need for SSH keys anymore.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html

Comment: I have tried ec2 instance connect and set up, everything in aws documentation but still i am not getting an option such as EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection). any help provided will be grateful.